# Is there a (parametric) distribution over sparse symmetric, binary matrix-valued random variables?

Tags: distributions, matrix, binary-data, sparse

The title says it all, really. I'm aware of the Wishart distribution for symmetric, nonnegative-definite matrix-valued random variables, and am looking for something along these lines, but for sparse symmetric, binary matrix-valued random variables. If necessary, I'm willing to forego the requirement that the matrices be sparse.

The context for this is the study of adjacency matrices for undirected graphs. In particular, “distant” vertices are unlikely to be connected, hence the sparsity (whereby “distant”, I mean dissimilarity between whatever it is that the vertices represent, measured in some suitable way).

Comment: Of course; there are *lots* of them! What other properties do you want? A simple example: Generate the lower diagonal entries as iid Bernoulli random variables with a small probability of success and "symmetrize".

Comment: OK, I walked into that one. I've added some clarification.

Comment: Is the "distance" an actual metric or just some pairwise "affinity" that, say, gets threshold to produce the edges?

Comment: In the simplest case, the distance is an actual distance (e.g., measurable in mm).

Comment: This sounds like the [random dot-product model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_graph#Random_graph_models).

Comment: @whuber: Maybe something similar, but even in the simple threshholding case when using the standard Euclidean metric it doesn't seem to quite fit. Or, have I come to that conclusion too hastily?